# Django Viewset Pagination throws serialization error

Tags: django, pagination, django-queryset, django-pagination, django-rest-viewsets

I have something like this:

Paginating Viewset:

```
class FeedViewSet(ModelViewSet):

    queryset = Feed.objects.all()
    serializer_class = FeedSerializer

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        paginator = pagination.LimitOffsetPagination()
        paginator.default_limit = 15
        paginator.limit = paginator.get_limit(request)
        paginator.offset = paginator.get_offset(request)
        feeds = paginator.paginate_queryset(Feed.objects.all(), request)
        return Response(
                data={
                        'feeds': feeds,
                        'limit': paginator.limit,
                        'offset': paginator.offset,
                        'overall_count': paginator.count
                    }
                )
```

Feeds Model:

```
class Feed(Base):
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    link = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    summary = models.TextField()
    published_date = models.DateTimeField()
    views = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    shares = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    source = models.ForeignKey(Source, on_delete=models.CASCADE, )
    reader = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='Bookmark')
```

Feed Serializer:

```
class FeedSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        fields = (
            'id',
            'headline',
            'link',
            'summary',
            'published_date',
            'views',
            'shares',
            'source',
            'created',
            'modified',

        )
        model = models.Feed
```

I am new to Django. I might be absolutely wrong here.

I have gone through official DRF here : http://www.django-rest-framework.org but couldn't figure out the correct way of implementing pagination.

I get something like this : `TypeError: Object of type 'Feed' is not JSON serializable`

What am I doing wrong? If this is not the right way to do it, how should it be done.
What changes do I need to make?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shoud pass to `Response` serialized feeds data. For this you need to use serializer:

```
def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    serializer = self.get_serializer_class()
    paginator = pagination.LimitOffsetPagination()
    paginator.default_limit = 15
    paginator.limit = paginator.get_limit(request)
    paginator.offset = paginator.get_offset(request)
    feeds = paginator.paginate_queryset(Feed.objects.all(), request)
    return Response(
            data={
                    'feeds': serializer(feeds, many=True).data,
                    'limit': paginator.limit,
                    'offset': paginator.offset,
                    'overall_count': paginator.count
                }
            )
```

Comment: I get this error after I did this : `Object of type 'ListSerializer' is not JSON serializable`

Comment: @WaqasHamid I've updated answer. Shuld be `serializer(feeds, many=True).data`.

Comment: Thanks! This works. Can you tell me how I could provide `next` and `previous` in data so I'm able to navigate to further results?

Comment: @WaqasHamid try to use `paginator.get_next_link()` and `paginator.get_previous_link()`.

Comment: Can you please upvote the question? I think it should reach out to beginners like me who absolutely feel lost when they begin Django. Thanks!